# How do I lazy load scope in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, lazy-loading

I have a chart generator plugin built with AngularJS and d3js, I want to load some charts based on a priority ranking, for example:

There are 6 charts with 3 priority levels:

- First priority: chart #1 & chart #5
- Second priority: chart #3
- Third priority: chart #2, chart #4 & chart #6

Note that you can't view a Second priority level chart before all of the first Priority charts have completely loaded.

How can I use lazy loading with my scope?

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
ngCharts.controller('WgListMixed', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $sce, $timeout, $compile, SharedDateScopes) {
        SharedDateScopes.getWidgetMixed(2).then(function(data_promised) {
            $rootScope.wgMixLists = data_promised;
            angular.forEach($rootScope.wgMixLists, function(widget) {
                var scope_name = widget.wg_id;
                var scope_name_v = widget.wg_id+"_v";
                $rootScope[scope_name] = widget.data[0];
                $rootScope[scope_name_v] = widget.data;
            });
        });
});
```

**Serivce**

```
ngCharts.service('SharedDateScopes', function($rootScope, $http, $q) {
        return {
            getWidgetMixed: function(dateRanges,stages) {
                var dataRange = <%=$data_range%>;
                if(typeof dateRanges !=="undefined") {
                    var dataRange = dateRanges;
                }
                var date_range_attr = "&date_range="+dataRange+"";
                if (typeof codename == "undefined") {
                    var date_range_attr = "";
                }
                var defer = $q.defer();
                $http.get('<%=[byt_control_root]%>/byt_reporting_widgets_manager?stage=mixed'+date_range_attr+'&widgets=<%=$bayt_mixed_widget%>').success(function (datas) {
                    defer.resolve(datas);
                });
                return defer.promise;
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: you can find complete example on github:

https://github.com/islamzatary/LegoCharts/

Answer (score 0):

Well this isn't as much a lazy loading problem as it is a timing problem.

Imagine you maintain a list for each level.

var firstPriority = [ {ID : 1, loaded : false} ,  {ID : 5, loaded : false} ]  ;

you start loading the data for 1 and 5 with promises of course. When each one finishes loading you change the flag in the array and then check the array to see if all elements in the array are now set to true. If they are then you start loading the next level, then the next.

This should do it and work for however many levels you have.